# fontawesome icon not spinning when unhidden with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

hopefully an easy one.. i've searched around but couldnt find anything to solve this.

I am using a simple fontawesome icon which is hidden on document load. The spinner works fine if i am not hidding it, however, if i apply the hidden class to it then i use jquery to show it the icon is displayed but its no longer animated, just shows as static icon.

Is there a better way that I should be un-hiding this element to make the animation work ?

**HERE IS THE CSS TO ANIMATE THE ICON**

```
.icon-spinner {
    display: none;
}
.load-animate {
    -animation: spin .7s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spin2 .7s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin2 {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframes spin {
    from { transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);}
    to { transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);}
}
```

**HERE IS THE HTML OF THE ICON INSIDE A BOOTSTRAP BUTTON**

```
<button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fa fa-spinner load-animate icon-spinner"></i>
Action</button>
```

**HERE IS THE JQUERY TO SHOW THE ICON BASED ON THE CLASS**

```
$('.icon-spinner').show();
```

Comment: How are you hiding the element on document load? This may, or may not, be helpful in answering your question but if it's explicitly that it's initially hidden causing the problem then it seems at least relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just wrap the icon with a span, and add the `icon-spinner` class to it.

demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ub4xk013/1/

```
<button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="icon-spinner"><i class="fa fa-spinner load-animate"></i></span>
Action</button>
```

hope that helps!

Comment: thanks Saeed! adding the span tags made all the difference.

Comment: i noticed though it works in chrome not firefox.. any ideas?

Comment: you will need to add "-moz-animation" to work in Firefox. more on this - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/  (scroll to bottom **Prefixes** area.)

Answer (score 0):

do like this.your font-awesome is not working.that is the case.add following online  scripts(js) and css to your project like this

```js
$('.icon-spinner').show();
```

```css
.icon-spinner {
    display: none;
}
.load-animate {
    -animation: spin .7s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spin2 .7s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin2 {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframes spin {
    from { transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);}
    to { transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fa fa-spinner load-animate icon-spinner"></i>
Action</button>
```